# Can a variant of the Dirichlet eta function converge for negative numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

It is known that the Dirichelt eta function, defined by

$$
\eta(s)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^s}
$$

converges conditionally on the open half-plane $\Re(s)>0$. This fact inspires the following question.

Is there a bounded function $f(n)\in\mathbb{Z}$ defined for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, such that the series

$$
\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{f(n)}{n^s}
$$

converges at least conditionally, in the sense

$$
\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\sum\limits_{n=1}^x\frac{f(n)}{n^s}<\infty
$$

on the half-plane $\Re(s)>c$, with some $c<0$? Or is this impossible for any such $f(n)$ and for any $c<0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course: you can take $f(n) = 0$ for all but finitely many $n$.  But that's the only way,
because the terms of a convergent series must go to $0$, and $|1/n^s| \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$ if $\Re(s) < 0$.

Comment: Excellent, thank you!